# How does jquery get a div's height right after loading dynamic content into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, while-loop

```
var contentparanum = 1;
while($(".container").height() < 200){
        paranum++;
        $(".content").append("<p></p>");
        $(".content p:nth-child("+contentparanum+")").load("getcontent.php?paranum="+paranum);
        contentparanum++;
        //use load() to add content into container, when the height of container is over 200px the loop stops
}
```

The problem is the loop never stops. I added alert(".container"); into the loop, I only get 0.It seems the height of the container can be obtained only after while loop is finished. How can I fix this problem?

---

I added the specific code

and the html code here

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Use callbacks to repeatedly load not an infinite loop which will block your load callback from ever executing.

Comment: Don't forget that `.load()` is asynchronous.

Comment: jQuery documentation says ".load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data", it does not say that it _adds_ content. Could you please show your load() code.

Comment: Is `.content` a child of `.container`?  Some HTML would be good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As .load() is asynchronous you will have to wait for the callback to make another call to load. Try this:

```
    var contentparanum = 1;
    var paranum = 1;

    $("#load").click(function () {
        // Checks if the height is below 200 before making the first call
        if($(".content").height() <200) 
        {
            LoadContent();
        }
    });

    function LoadContent() {

        $(".content").append("<p></p>");

        $(".content p:nth-child(" + contentparanum + ")").load("getcontent.php?paranum=" + paranum,
           // This is the callback function 
           function (response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
            else {
                // Checks if the height is below 200 and if yes makes a recursive call 
                if ($(".content").height() < 200) {
                    contentparanum++;
                    paranum++;
                    LoadContent();
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: The content div is empty by default, the content of it is severals <p> tags, which are loaded one by one using load(). So I used while to do the job, a single if cannot help.

Comment: In that case just ignore the first checking.The $("#load").click(function () {}) will be like $("#load").click(function () {
     LoadContent();
});    After the first LoadContent() call is completed the call back function will be called and it will check the height and decide to call the LoadContent() recursively.

Answer (score -1):

```
function loadContent(paranum) {
    $("#container").append("<p></p>")
    $("#container").children().last().load("getcontent.php?paranum="+paranum, function() {
        if($("#container").height() < 200) {
            window.setTimeout(loadContent, 0, paranum+1);
        }
    });
    }

$(function() {loadContent(1);});
```

Comment: you do not need the `setTimeout(..., 0)` because load is already async. a simple `loadContent()` would be enough here.

Comment: No, it must be ensured that loadContent is called after the page has loaded. Just stripping the "window.setTimeout(...)" won't work. Alternatively one could do something like $(function() {loadContent(1);});

Comment: `window.setTimeout(...,0);` does not ensure that the script is executed when the page is loaded. it just says execute the callback as fast as possible when the current execution finished. so it could be executed before page finished loading (e.g. if you have chunked transfered). so `window.setTimeout(...,0);` is not an alternative to `$( ... );`. also passing the callback as string is bad practices because it will break minification tools and validation.